# Как проверить соответствие текущей даты и дня рождения

Tags: java, дата

Есть следующая задача:

- В базе хранятся дни рождения сотрудников - отдельно дата, отдельно месяц, год не важен.
- Необходимо сравнить текущую дату (день, месяц) с днями рождения в списке сотрудников и в результате вернуть ID'шник того сотрудника, у которого сегодня день рождения.

Понимаю, что делать это надо через цикл, но как именно это реализовать, и главное как вернуть ID'шник именинника не понимаю.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); // получаем текущую дату

        int month = date.getMonthValue(); //месяц
        int dayOfMonth = date.getDayOfMonth(); // день

        int test_dayOfMonth = 19; // тестовый день, позже результат запроса из таблицы
        int test_month = 9; // тестовый месяц, позже результат запроса из таблицы

        matcher_two(dayOfMonth, month, test_dayOfMonth, test_month);
    }

    private static void matcher_two(int day, int month, int t_day, int t_month){
        if (day == t_day && month == t_month)
            System.out.println("День рождения");
    }
}
```

Comment: А где собственно у вас код для работы с базой или хотя бы списком сотрудников?  Если у вас есть база данных, то формируется соответствующий запрос (хотя бы SQL через JDBC `SELECT id FROM employees WHERE birth_day=:birthDay AND birth_month=:birthMonth`) -- будет возвращаться _список_ айдишников.  Или же у вас имеется список сотрудников, который можно отфильтровать.

Comment: В какой базе? Приведи пример кода, где хранится список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть список сотрудников `List<Employee>`, где `Employee` -- некий класс-сущность типа такого:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int birthDay;
    private int birthMonth;
}
```

то этот список можно отфильтровать и преобразовать в список айдишников при помощи Stream API:

```java
public static List<Long> getCelebrantIds(List<Employee> employees) {
    final LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    return employees.stream()
        .filter(emp -> emp.getBirthDay() == today.getDayOfMonth() && emp.getBirthMonth() == today.getMonthValue())
        .map(Employee::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // или toList() для Java 16+
}
```

---

Если для работы с базой используется Spring Data (JPA/Hibernate), тогда для получения списка айдишников и/или сотрудников потребуется дописать метод(ы) в репозитории, которые следует вызвать, передавая параметры текущей даты:

```java
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    // список айдишников
    @Query(value = "SELECT e.id FROM Employee e WHERE e.birthDay = :birthDay AND e.birthMonth = :birthMonth")
    public List<Long> getCelebrantIds(
        @Param("birthDay") int birthDay,
        @Param("birthMonth") int birthMonth
    );

    // список сотрудников
    List<Employee> findByBirthDayAndBirthMonth(int birthDay, int birthMonth);
}
```

```java
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repo;

    public List<Long> getCelebrantIds() {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        return repo.getCelebrantIds(today.getDayOfMonth(), today.getMonthValue());
    }

    public List<Employee> getCelebrants() {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        return repo.findByBirthDayAndBirthMonth(today.getDayOfMonth(), today.getMonthValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны входные данные, но как вариант есть такой enum "ChronoUnit".
Вот пример его работы:

```
long between = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(2023, 9, 21), LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println(between); 

//  ответ 1
т.е. сравниваются две даты и выводится количество дней разницы.
```

(LocalDate.now() == 2023, 9, 22).
Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Вроде бы у автора вопроса всё доступно изложено -- для _текущей даты_ (`LocalDate.now()`) нужно проверить, является ли она _днём рождения_ для некоего сотрудника, т.е. сравниваются только день и месяц.  Ваш ответ немного не о том.